# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ awesomequotes.FullScreenViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, eclipse

It's apparently a question that has been asked multiple times.but i am not able to find any solution anywhere. i am creating a app called awesomequotes and all this app contains images but whenever i click on the images to view in full screen it shows a error "unfortunately, aweseomequotes has stopped". i tracked the logcat errors it shows....

```
09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity          ComponentInfo{com.example.awesomequotes/com.example.awesomequotes.FullScreenViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2355)

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5520)

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): at com.example.awesomequotes.FullScreenViewActivity.onCreate(FullScreenViewActivity.java:54)

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)

09-21 15:45:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(6967): ... 11 more
```

i have various classed but here i am only copying code of FullScreenActivity.java and layout file for full screen activity.

**FullScreenActivity.java**

```
package com.example.awesomequotes;
import app.AppController;
import picasa.model.Wallpaper;
import util.Utils;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageContainer;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageListener;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;


public class FullScreenViewActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = FullScreenViewActivity.class
            .getSimpleName();
    public static final String TAG_SEL_IMAGE = "selectedImage";
    private Wallpaper selectedPhoto;
    private ImageView fullImageView;
    private LinearLayout llSetWallpaper, llDownloadWallpaper;
    private Utils utils;
    private ProgressBar pbLoader;

    // Picasa JSON response node keys
    private static final String TAG_ENTRY = "entry",
            TAG_MEDIA_GROUP = "media$group",
            TAG_MEDIA_CONTENT = "media$content", TAG_IMG_URL = "url",
            TAG_IMG_WIDTH = "width", TAG_IMG_HEIGHT = "height";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        llSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        llDownloadWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_image);

        fullImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFullscreen);
        llSetWallpaper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSetWallpaper);
        llDownloadWallpaper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llDownloadWallpaper);
        pbLoader = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbLoader);

        // hide the action bar in fullscreen mode
        getActionBar().hide();

        utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext());

        // layout click listeners
        llSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);
        llDownloadWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);

        // setting layout buttons alpha/opacity
        llSetWallpaper.getBackground().setAlpha(70);
        llDownloadWallpaper.getBackground().setAlpha(70);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        selectedPhoto = (Wallpaper) i.getSerializableExtra(TAG_SEL_IMAGE);

        // check for selected photo null
        if (selectedPhoto != null) {

            // fetch photo full resolution image by making another json request
            fetchFullResolutionImage();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.msg_unknown_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetching image fullresolution json
     * */
    private void fetchFullResolutionImage() {
        String url = selectedPhoto.getPhotoJson();

        // show loader before making request
        pbLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llSetWallpaper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llDownloadWallpaper.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // volley's json obj request
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url,
                null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG,
                                "Image full resolution json: "
                                        + response.toString());
                        try {
                            // Parsing the json response
                            JSONObject entry = response
                                    .getJSONObject(TAG_ENTRY);

                            JSONArray mediacontentArry = entry.getJSONObject(
                                    TAG_MEDIA_GROUP).getJSONArray(
                                    TAG_MEDIA_CONTENT);

                            JSONObject mediaObj = (JSONObject) mediacontentArry
                                    .get(0);

                            String fullResolutionUrl = mediaObj
                                    .getString(TAG_IMG_URL);

                            // image full resolution widht and height
                            final int width = mediaObj.getInt(TAG_IMG_WIDTH);
                            final int height = mediaObj.getInt(TAG_IMG_HEIGHT);

                            Log.d(TAG, "Full resolution image. url: "
                                    + fullResolutionUrl + ", w: " + width
                                    + ", h: " + height);

                            ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController
                                    .getInstance().getImageLoader();

                            // We download image into ImageView instead of
                            // NetworkImageView to have callback methods
                            // Currently NetworkImageView doesn't have callback
                            // methods

                            imageLoader.get(fullResolutionUrl,
                                    new ImageListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onErrorResponse(
                                                VolleyError arg0) {
                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                                    getString(R.string.msg_wall_fetch_error),
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(
                                                ImageContainer response,
                                                boolean arg1) {
                                            if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                                                // load bitmap into imageview
                                                fullImageView
                                                        .setImageBitmap(response
                                                                .getBitmap());
                                                adjustImageAspect(width, height);

                                                // hide loader and show set &
                                                // download buttons
                                                pbLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                llSetWallpaper
                                                        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                llDownloadWallpaper
                                                        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    getString(R.string.msg_unknown_error),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        // unable to fetch wallpapers
                        // either google username is wrong or
                        // devices doesn't have internet connection
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                getString(R.string.msg_wall_fetch_error),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

        // Remove the url from cache
        AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(url);

        // Disable the cache for this url, so that it always fetches updated
        // json
        jsonObjReq.setShouldCache(false);

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }

    /**
     * Adjusting the image aspect ration to scroll horizontally, Image height
     * will be screen height, width will be calculated respected to height
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void adjustImageAspect(int bWidth, int bHeight) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        if (bWidth == 0 || bHeight == 0)
            return;

        int sHeight = 0;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            sHeight = size.y;
        } else {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            sHeight = display.getHeight();
        }

        int new_width = (int) Math.floor((double) bWidth * (double) sHeight
                / (double) bHeight);
        params.width = new_width;
        params.height = sHeight;

        Log.d(TAG, "Fullscreen image new dimensions: w = " + new_width
                + ", h = " + sHeight);

        fullImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    /**
     * View click listener
     * */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) fullImageView.getDrawable())
                .getBitmap();
        switch (v.getId()) {
        // button Download Wallpaper tapped
        case R.id.llDownloadWallpaper:
            utils.saveImageToSDCard(bitmap);
            break;
        // button Set As Wallpaper tapped
        case R.id.llSetWallpaper:
            utils.setAsWallpaper(bitmap);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

this is the layout file

**activity_fullscreen_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbLoader"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
    </ProgressBar>

    <!-- Scroll view for fullscreen preview -->

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgFullscreen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <!-- Set as wallpaper button -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSetWallpaper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_corner"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ico_apply" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/set_wallpaper"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Download wallpaper button -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llDownloadWallpaper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_corner"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ico_download" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/download_wallpaper"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.awesomequotes"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />


    <application
        android:name="app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                 </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FullScreenViewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/action_settings"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>







    </application>

</manifest>
```

I would really appreciate the help. its been more than 2 days since i am stucked here.

thank you

Comment: What were you able to find out when debugging/manually stepping through this code?

Comment: at com.example.awesomequotes.FullScreenViewActivity.onCreate(FullScreenViewActivity.java:54)

this line of code is causing null pointer exception

Comment: i have double checked the code.....not able to find any error? i know this FullScreenViewActivity.onCreate(FullScreenViewActivity‌​.java:54 is giving the error but everythings seems alright there.

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate()

```
llSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
llDownloadWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_image);

fullImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFullscreen);
llSetWallpaper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSetWallpaper);
llDownloadWallpaper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llDownloadWallpaper);
pbLoader = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbLoader);
```

you set listener before you found views. You should `findViewById` first

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your `onCreate` method:

```
    llSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    llDownloadWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_image);

    fullImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFullscreen);
    llSetWallpaper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSetWallpaper);
    llDownloadWallpaper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llDownloadWallpaper);
    pbLoader = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbLoader);
```

You are setting the listeners before instatiating the items, it should be something like this:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_image);

    //First you instantiate the items  

    fullImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFullscreen);
    llSetWallpaper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSetWallpaper);
    llDownloadWallpaper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llDownloadWallpaper);
    pbLoader = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbLoader);

    //Then you set the listener

    llDownloadWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: and one more thing do u know how to show images from my app on unlock screen.....it would be very cool if it will happen.

Comment: Hi @nishantjaisinghani, that is a very complex question to answer in the comments. I think you should accept this answer and start a new question for that